# Trouble setting up lucene on Mac OSX

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Lucene to work on Mac OS 10.7.5

I downloaded the binaries from http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/demo.html.

I changed my classpath

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/me/Downloads/lucene-4.5.1/demo/lucene-demo-4.5.1.jar:/Users/me/Downloads/lucene-4.5.1/core/lucene-core-4.5.1.jar
```

Now I'm trying to run it.

```
$java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles /Users/me/Downloads/lucene-4.5.1/src

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

It's not working.  Can someone give me a step-by-step guide to getting up and running with Lucene.  I have a simple task I want to do achieve, which is searching for text in a directory of files in a more efficient way than *grep*.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: copy the error / stacktrace you see

Comment: @FredericClose  Sorry, forgot.  did it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll also need to add two more jars to your classpath: `lucene-analyzers-common-{version}.jar` to fix this problem, and `lucene-queryparser-{version}.jar` to fix the next one.  [More recent demo documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_1/demo/overview-summary.html#Setting_your_CLASSPATH) makes this clear (the documentation you linked to is for version 2.9.4)